# Best way to get data, display it in a list and linking each item to a detail page

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a project with angularjs and have a bit of trouble figuring out some things.
So basically I'm getting a .json via an api which contains some university courses.
I like to display them and when I click on one of them the detail page should be displayed.

```
function getcourses($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope){

$scope.init = function (){
    $scope.apiroot = "http://....";
    $http.get($scope.apiroot + 'courses.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.courses = response.data.courses;

    })
};
$scope.selectCourse = function (index) {
        $scope.detailcourse = $scope.courses[index];
        $location.path('/course');
    };
}
```

courses.html:

```
<table ng-controller="getcourses" data-ng-init="init()">
...
<li ng-repeat="course in courses">
    <a ng-click="selectCourse($index)" ng-href="">{{course.title}}</a>
</li>
```

course.html:

```
<div class="panel panel-small" ng-controller="getcourses">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{detailcourse.title}}: {{detailcourse.subtitle}}</div>
      <div class="list-group">
        <class="list-group-item">{{detailcourse.description}}</class>
      </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

This way, when I click on a link and get redirected nothing is shown.
I guess because it gets all the courses again as soon as the other page gets loaded?
I got it working with a rootScope but I think that's not very pretty.
So what's the best way to do something like this?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to setup a separate route for the course details page. Then you can use `$routeParams` to load the details for that course.

Comment: How would I use that? I could route to let's say /coursetitle but then I would only have the title available through routeParams on the detail page right? Because the courses object is gone again.

Comment: You would need to make another call to the server to get the data for just that course. If it were me I would probably use something like the course_id if one is available in the route. For example your route could be /course/54321, when that route loads you get the course_id and query the server to retrieve and then display that data. When I have some free time I could work on a example of how that could work.

Comment: I think there is already a good example of exact the same task in [official Angular tutorial.](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat)